# Can I make a GUI Terminal use basic screen/tmux keyboard shortcuts

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am (for an experiment) trying to use the tabs inside GNOME terminal, rather than using tmux.

My instrinct still goes to <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> for open new tab, etc.

Is there a way to configure GNOME terminal or any other GUI terminal use these shortcuts, at least the basic ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the keyboard shortcuts of GNOME Terminal in its settings, but that doesn't support multi-stroke key combos. I'm also not aware of any other GUI terminal emulators that would support it.